# Numbers of students registered for various courses

Tags: combinatorics

I have a probability problem that I’m struggling with. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the problem:

A class has 28 students. In this class, each student is registered in 2 languages courses (at most) chosen among English, German or Spanish. The number of students registered in each of these 3 languages lessons is 25 for English, 18 for German and 13 for Spanish.

1)  There are many students registered for both English and Spanish. **True or False ?**

2)  All Students registered in German are registered in “English” ? **True ? False ? We cannot tell ?**

I cannot figure out how to find out this.
Can you please help on this?

Regards,

Comment: How many are "many"? More than one? More than half?

Comment: Yup, the question is not clear on that part. However, it should be much easier if you draw a Venn Diagram to depict the situation.

Comment: I agree with you, this is not very clear. But this is how the problem was stated. Nothing more was added. Like you, I suppose, it means more than one. Can somebody show me how to use a Venn diagram in this particular case please?

Comment: @XCoder 1) Do you actually mean `more` by `many`? 2) Do you mean `all students registered in German are also registered in English`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to arrive at the solution:

1. There are 28 students in the class, 25 of which are in the English course. So how many students are not in the English course?
2. There are 13 students in the Spanish course. Given the answer to the previous question, how many *at least* have to also be in the English course? (This gives you the answer to the first question)
3. Given the last answer, what is the minimum number of people attending the English course that also attend the Spanish course?
4. Given that no one has all three courses, how many people in the English course can at most attend the German course?
5. How does that number compare to the number of people attending the German course? (This answers the second question)

Comment: For the first question : 3 are not taking English, so 3 are in Spanish and German. 13 are in Spanish, among which 3 are in Spanish and German. So 10 are in Spanish and English ? Is that the way to see it ? For the second one, I'm still trying to understand...

Comment: @XCoder As $10$ are attending both English and Spanish and no one can take more than $2$ courses, only $8$ can take both English and German. I think you can find the rest.

Comment: @f.nasim: Are you sure ? I think 15 attend English and German, not 8 ? Since 15 is less than 25, all English students cannot attend German courses. So the second answer is "False".

Comment: @XCoder I think I am. You also agree that $10$ are taking Spanish and English and no one takes more than $2$ courses then how it can't be? Is it clear?

Comment: @XCoder I'm so sorry I did it in rush. You're right. Indeed at most $15$ can take both English and German. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to  f.nasim and celtschk. The question was simpler than it looks.