# Class of 100 students, 10 who speak German, 20 who speak Italian, 30 who speak Spanish, 8 who speak both Italian and Spanish, 3 speak all 3 languages

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

**How many people in the class speak none of the 3 languages?**

10 speak German, minus the 3 who speak all languages is **7**.

20 speak Italian, minus the 3 who speak all languages and the 8 who speak both Italian and Spanish so **9**.

20 speak Spanish, minus the 3 who speak all languages and the 8 who speak both Italian and Spanish so **19**.

Add back in the 3 and 8 people who spoke multiple languages = **11**

So the amount of people who don't speak any of the 3 languages should be:

**100 - 7 - 9 - 19 + 11 = 76**

Have I gotten the correct answer or have I miscounted somewhere?

Comment: There have been a lot of questions like this asked and answered here. Maybe you could just read some and see for yourself.

Comment: E.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406683/numbers-of-students-registered-for-various-courses and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416914/how-many-students-like-none-of-the-toppings-principle-of-inclusion-exclusion and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263823/how-to-use-inclusion-exclusion-to-solve-this-problem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020583/combinatorics-how-many-people-speak-german-french-english-and-portuguese and no doubt several others.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  Should I delete this post then?

Comment: It doesn't look good to delete a question once it has an answer, Magi. This website has been here for ten years now, and pretty much every question that could be asked about lower level undergrad math has been asked and answered, so it's always a good idea to do some searching for duplicates before posting. Unfortunately it's not always easy to find duplicates, even when there are plenty of them. So, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this self explanatory diagram:

[image]

So the answer is $100-7-22-12=59$

If you start drawing this diagramm, it is clear which number comes in which area.
You could start writing all numbers you know first.

But then you count to many. For example if you write a 10 into (ger) and also a 3 into the intersection of (ger), (esp) and (it) then you count 3 to many. The 3 in the intersection are also in (ger), so the 10 becomes a 7. And so on.

Also every student who speaks three languages also speaks two, and so on.

> 20 speak Italian, minus the 3 who speak all languages and the 8 who speak both Italian and Spanish so **9**.

Here you miscounted.

If you subtract 8, you subtract 3 to many, because you already subtracted three students who speak every language, but these students are also among the 8 who speak two languages.

> 20 speak Spanish, minus the 3 who speak all languages and the 8 who speak both Italian and Spanish so 19.

Same mistake.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't there need to be another 8 subtracted from the total to account for the 3 people who speak all 3 languages and the 5 people who speak Italian and Spanish?  7, 22, and 12 are just the people who speak one language only. I'm looking for the number of people who don't speak ANY of the languages presented.

Comment: People who do not speak any language are not in the union of those 3 circles. We tried to find how many people are in this circle and this number is 41, so there are 59 who do not speak any language of these 3.